# Frequency to submit sitemap to search engines

Tags: search-engines, sitemap

I have went live with my site and being new to search engines and SEO fields not sure what should be the best way to handle *sitemap.xml*.

I have created *sitemap.xml* and submitted it to:

- Google using Webmaster Tools
- Yahoo/Bing using Bing Webmater Tools
- Ask.com

Now since site will get updated every 2-3 times per week I am not sure what should be the best approach.

1. Do I need to submit *sitemap.xml* again?
2. If I need to submit *sitemap.xml* again and again what should be the frequency to submit that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need to re-sumbit your sitemap to the search engines. They will regularly re-crawl and index your sitemap and pickup any changes to it. All you need to do is make sure you keep it up to date with any new pages you have added to your site.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the new-er *robots.txt* approach, the best thing may be to add the location of your sitemap to your *robots.txt* for clarity & ease of discovery, and keep your sitemap location up to date there...

You also should probably follow the sitemap protocol by telling the search engines the likely update frequency of the various urls that are in your sitemap.